# ImportError: No module named spiders on mac OS using Homebrew installation package

Tags: python, scrapy, homebrew

All,

I followed the following steps from scrapy.org to updated default system packages and install scrapy, the open source framework for building spiders found here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/install.html

1. I ran the `xcode-select --install` command from terminal
2. ran the command to install hombebrew package: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
3. I tried to run this command, but don't know if I correctly updated, I copied and pasted this exactly: `echo "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc`
4. per the installation directions on scrapy, I tried to verify  that changes had take place: `source ~/.bashrc`
5. I ran the command: `brew install python`
6. ran the command : `brew update; brew upgrade python`
7. ran the command: `pip install Scrapy`

I wanted to be very clear with the above commands, trying to update and install packages.  I proceeded to follow directions to create a project, define items and create my first spider.

**Lastly** when I ran the command `scrapy crawl dmoz` I get the below error message

**crawl command with output and error message**

```
Romans-MBP:tutorial Roman$ scrapy crawl dmoz
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
     sys.exit(execute())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 141, in execute
     cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 238, in __init__
super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 129, in __init__
self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 325, in _get_spider_loader
return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 33, in from_settings
return cls(settings)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 20, in __init__
self._load_all_spiders()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 28, in _load_all_spiders
for module in walk_modules(name):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 63, in walk_modules
mod = import_module(path)
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
 ImportError: No module named spiders
 Romans-MBP:tutorial Roman$
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in `scrapy/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/[your_spider].py` the name of your spider, that should be run with `scrapy crawl` command. In the example below, the name is `dmozdirectory` and the run command is `scrapy crawl dmozdirectory`

Example:

```
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmozdirectory"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
```

Also, you should be in the root directory of your project when running that command, in `scrapy/tutorial/`

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I went through my code and made sure the name in the command,  is the same value as the "name = "dmoz" in the spider.  

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]

Contents of the **/scrapy/tutorial/** directory
__init__.py items.py settings.py spiders
__init__.pyc pipelines.py settings.pyc

this is the command
scrapy crawl dmoz

I even changed the name from "dmoz" to "dmozdirectory" and "dmoz_spider", both in the name field in the spider and command

Comment: Your project is named scrapy?

Comment: yes, I believe so.  I have checked the *.py files where I had to make edits and I see the import command as the following for each file.  Also, there is a scrapy.cfg file in the /scrapy/tutorial/ directory.

**items.py contents**
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()

**dmoz.py contents**
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [